# How to remove "Sort by Items per page" in drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I have a Drupal7 website. I have a Block-View in it with a title , header and a footer .
When I apply the view to the desired region , a "sort by Items per page" line show up on the webpage. I have not applied any sort criteria . How do i get rid of it ? Thanks !
[The screen shot for the view is here and there is nothing in the Sort Criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJNmt.png)

The code for the view is here

> SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, 'node' AS
>   field_data_field_event_image_node_entity_type, 'node' AS
>   field_data_field_event_date_node_entity_type, 'node' AS
>   field_data_field_event_location_node_entity_type FROM  {node} node
>   LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_event_date} field_data_field_event_date ON
>   node.nid = field_data_field_event_date.entity_id AND
>   (field_data_field_event_date.entity_type = 'node' AND
>   field_data_field_event_date.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (node.status =
>   '1') AND (node.type IN  ('event')) AND
>   (DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(field_data_field_event_date.field_event_date_value,
>   SEC_TO_TIME(-14400)), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-09-13') ))

Comment: Can you put up screenshot or code of that view here in question?

Comment: Screenshot is not clear, putup code here